# Sql query that combines the name of all its parents name

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I’m trying to create a column that combines the name of all its parent names.

For example.

Projects:

```
ID  PARENT_ID   NAME    COMBINED_NAME
1                A         A
2      1         B         B / A
3      2         C         C / B / A
```

I have tried using connect by but have failed to even get what I need.

```
SELECT  TP.PROJECT_SEQ,
        LEVEL,
        SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(TP.PROJECT_NAME, ' / ') AS PROJECT_DIR,
        TP.PROJECT_NAME,
        TP.PARENT_SEQ
FROM    TFS_PROJECTS TP
START WITH TP.PROJECT_SEQ IN (SELECT TPSUB.PROJECT_SEQ FROM TFS_PROJECTS TPSUB)
CONNECT BY PRIOR TP.PROJECT_SEQ = TP.PARENT_SEQ
```

I finally resolved it! No thanks to people deleting, removing and holding questions on stackoverflow. I'm actually thankful no one gave me the answer as I learned a lot from this.

Anyways in case anyone runs into a similar problem they need to solve.

```
SELECT              TP.PROJECT_SEQ,
                    TP.PROJECT_NAME,
                    LTRIM(MAX(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(TP.PROJECT_NAME, ' / ')) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY LEVEL DESC), ' / ') AS PROJECT_DIR
FROM                TFS_PROJECTS TP
CONNECT BY PRIOR    TP.PROJECT_SEQ = TP.PARENT_SEQ
GROUP BY            TP.PROJECT_SEQ,
                    TP.PROJECT_NAME
```

I used the MAX / KEEP to get the root project only. I'm not really good at explaining it but you can reverse engineer this and understand what's happening. Maybe one of the people who put a hold on this can actually put an explanation forward instead of clicking a the delete, hold or remove question button. It's almost as if you get points by doing that.

Comment: `CONNECT BY` is the right way to do it in Oracle.  Add your query to the question, apparently it has a problem.

Comment: Give us something to start with.  Instead of saying "I have tried using connect by", please show us the code that you have tried, and explain what it didn't do correctly.  Then we can go from there.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm#i2060615

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT              TP.PROJECT_SEQ,
                    TP.PROJECT_NAME,
                    LTRIM(MAX(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(TP.PROJECT_NAME, ' / ')) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY LEVEL DESC), ' / ') AS PROJECT_DIR
FROM                TFS_PROJECTS TP
CONNECT BY PRIOR    TP.PROJECT_SEQ = TP.PARENT_SEQ
GROUP BY            TP.PROJECT_SEQ,
                    TP.PROJECT_NAME
```

I used the DENSE_RANK and ORDER BY LEVEL DESC to get the full path of each project. Then the KEEP and FIRST allows me to keep just that full path with the highest level possible. I'm not really good at explaining it but someone can expand on this in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code

```
begin
   update TFS_PROJECTS t set t.COMBINED_NAME = null;
   update TFS_PROJECTS t set t.COMBINED_NAME = t.NAME  where id = 1;


begin
 for i in (select *
            from (select e.id, e.PARENT_ID, e.NAME   , e.COMBINED_NAME
                    from TFS_PROJECTS e
                  connect by prior e.id = e.PARENT_ID
                   start with e.id = 1)
           where id != 1) loop
  update TFS_PROJECTS
     set COMBINED_NAME =i.Name ||'/'||
         (select COMBINED_NAME from TFS_PROJECTS where id =i.PARENT_ID)  
   where id = i.id;
  commit;
end loop;

end
```